# Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption .NET package and ApiVersion

Tags: c#, azure, consumption

I am trying to use the [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption/) 3.0.2 package to access the usage and consumption data.

However in the call to `UsageDetails.List` I get the following error:

> Subscription scope usage is not supported for current api version. Please use api version after 2019-10-01

Is there a new version of the package (or is there expected to be) that supports this version?

What alternatives do I have in the meantime?

I can directly use a GET against

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-10-01
```

but is there any other option?

UPDATED WITH CODE

Request code:

```
AuthenticationResult result = GetToken();
Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new 
Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
ConsumptionManagementClient client = new 
ConsumptionManagementClient(tokenCredentials);
client.SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId I would like to check"; 

var usage = client.UsageDetails.List(); // Exception here with API Version
```

Auth Code sample:

```
private static AuthenticationResult GetToken()
{
    string clientId = "MyappId";

    string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
    var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithRedirectUri("https://localhost")
        .WithTenantId("TenantId I want to check")
        .Build();
    var task = app.GetAccountsAsync();
    task.Wait();
    var accounts = task.Result;
    try
    {
        var task1 = app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
        task1.Wait();
        return task1.Result;
    }
    catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
    {
        var task2 = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        task2.Wait();
        return task2.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you referred to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/consumption/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Consumption/tests/ScenarioTests/SubscriptionUsagesTests.cs?

Comment: I have just created an issue asking in https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: Code provided. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell me your subscription type?

Comment: Regarding `ConsumptionManagementClient`, we have no way to set `api version` and we just can get `api version`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.consumption.consumptionmanagementclient.apiversion?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Consumption_ConsumptionManagementClient_ApiVersion

Comment: Sorry for the delay: Subscription type - CSP : 0145P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, we can initialize `ServiceClientCredentials` to create `ConsumptionManagementClient` and  the `ServiceClientCredentials` has method `ProcessHttpRequestAsync` which we can use to recreate request

For example

1. Implement `ServiceClientCredentials`

```
class CustomLoginCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
    {
       
        private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
        public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
        {
           string clientId = "MyappId";

    string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
    var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithRedirectUri("https://localhost")
        .WithTenantId("TenantId I want to check")
        .Build();
            var task = app.GetAccountsAsync();
            task.Wait();
            var accounts = task.Result;
            try
            {
                var task1 = app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
                task1.Wait();
                AuthenticationToken= task1.Result.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                var task2 = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                task2.Wait();
                AuthenticationToken= task2.Result.AccessToken;
            }
            
        }
        public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
            }

            if (AuthenticationToken == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Provider Cannot Be Null");
            }

            var url = request.RequestUri.ToString().Split('?')[0] + "?";
            var querys = request.RequestUri.ToString().Split('?')[1].Split('&');
            for (var i = 1; i <= querys.Length; i++)
            {

                if (querys[i - 1].StartsWith("api-version"))
                {
                    url += "api-version=2019-10-01";
                }
                else
                {
                    url += querys[i - 1];
                }


                if (i < querys.Length)
                {

                    url += "&";
                }



            }

            Console.WriteLine(url);

            request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);



            await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        }



    }
```

2. Get details

```
 var cred = new CustomLoginCredentials();
ConsumptionManagementClient client = new ConsumptionManagementClient(cred);
client.SubscriptionId = "SubscriptionId I would like to check"; 
var usage = client.UsageDetails.List();
```